# SQL Dynamic Pivot on Category Names 1/0 0 instead of null

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have data as follows:

```
Name   CategoryName
Test1  cat1
Test1  cat2
Test2  cat1
Test3  cat2
```

I want to display it so that I get a list of users with 1/0 (true/false) under the category name:

```
Name   cat1  cat2
Test1  1     1
Test2  1     0
Test3  0     1
```

Using the following sql I can generate the 1 but I cannot work out how to get the 0.

*note: The sql to get the users in the categories is very much simplified from what I actually am using so may not be totally correct*

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName) 
            FROM   Category c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        set @query = 'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT Name 
                       CategoryName,
                            1 as assigned
                FROM        User INNER JOIN
                      UserCategory ON User.ID = UserCategory.UserID             

           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(assigned)
                for CategoryName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

            execute(@query)
```

Can I update this to generate a 1/0, rather than a 1/null?

**EDIT - Solution**
Thanks to @Tab Allerman

I updated this so I had 2 cols variables

```
SET @colsForSelect = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName)
            FROM   Category c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

and kept the original @cols. 
I used the  @colsForSelect in the beginning of the query and then the original @cols in the 'pivot for'.
I hope this makes sense to anyone who needs help

Comment: ISNULL()?  COALESCE()?

Comment: Where would I add that? in the pivot bit? This is the first pivot I've ever tried.

Comment: In the STUFF.   Around the Category name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName)
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get this to work as this makes the  pivot 
            (
                 max(assigned)
                for CategoryName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p have  [  ISNULL(cat1,0) AS cat1 ] in it and throws an incorrect syntax error (with one category)

Comment: Ignore that. I created two @cols variables. The new one for the select and the original one for the pivot